# C++ sleep() function works not as expected

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sleep

colleagues! I tried to use the `sleep()` function in my code together with the `system()` function. The code is supposed to display the first message, and then count down, every time print out the number of seconds left and waiting 1 second. Then the screen should be cleared. I want to make just a simple text animation. But the program does not work as expected! I checked my code and it looks like I have no syntax or logical error. When I compile and run this code, first it waits for five seconds and then prints out the message to stdout without even waiting, and clears the screen immediately. I think that this is a runtime error, although it should not logically happen. If the following information is relevant, I compile and run my C++ programs from the Linux terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>   // includes system();
#include <unistd.h>  // includes sleep();
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  cout << "Clearing the screen in: ";
  for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << i << " ";
    sleep(1);  // takes seconds
  }
  system("clear");

  return 0;
}
```