# VSCODE need real time output and sleep causing long build time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently installed vscode for C++. I have C++, C++ extension pack, C# extensions, cmake, cmake tools, and code runner. Currently i have this little program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"A";

    sleep(2);

    std::cout<<"B";

    return 0;
}
```

The output I expect: A (wait 2 seconds) B
The output I got: (wait 2 seconds) AB

It would wait until the program is done running before printing. Is there a way to make the output real time?

Another problem I have is extensive build time due to sleep(). with sleep(20 i have a small build time. changing nothing except sleep(2) to sleep(30) increases my build time by 30 seconds. The longer the sleep the longer the build time.

https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/973

This problem above is same as mine but uses python and did not fix my issue in c++

Comment: Output is buffered. If you add a newline to the end of your string, `std::endl`, or `std::flush` it should show the first line before the sleep.

Comment: Try again with either `"A\n"` or `"A" << std::flush` or call `std::cout.flush()`  Also, I disbelieve when you say _The longer the sleep the longer the build time._  Because, at least for me, "build time" means "compile and link" time, as opposed to "run" time.  Also, possible duplicate of: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/1563833)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631384/c-understanding-buffer-and-stdendl which is what I would have searched for, but it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n which I would not have searched for.

Answer (score 0):

dropping a line by std::endl did fix my problem as buffering was my problem. as for the build time it seems to be a problem i can ignore for now and do more research into the future.